# find in file and replace

Tags: python, regex

I have a file, containing numbers and strings, like this.

```
1
something ASDF 1,2,3,4,5
2
something2 ASDFG 1,2,5,8,9
etc
```

between something and ASDF there is a tab

I would like to write two tabs after the "simple" lines.
output should be the same:

```
1\t\t
something ASDF 1,2,3,4,5
2\t\t
something2 ASDFG 1,2,5,8,9
etc
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: how to find this lines

Comment: So what have you written up to this point? Have you written anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('a-file', 'r+') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            line = line.rstrip() + '\t\t\n'
        lines.append(line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(lines)
```

[str.isdigit()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

regular expression alternative: `if re.search('^\d+$', line) != None`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('f1') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if line[0].isdigit():
            print line.strip() + '\t\t'
        else:
            print line.strip()
```

output (cortesy of `cat -t`):

```
1^I^I
something ASDF 1,2,3,4,5
2^I^I
something2 ASDFG 1,2,5,8,9
etc
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it prints 1\t\t then 2\t\t but skips the "something" lines

Answer (score 0):

a three lines solution

```
with open('a-file') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        print "%s%s" % (l[:-1], '\t\t' if i % 2 == 0 else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

in 2 lines:

```
with open('f1') as f:
    ['%s%s' % (l.strip(), '\t\t' if l[0].isdigit() else '') for l in f]
```